# Laravel 4.1 PHPUnit Test: Call to a member function with() on a non-object

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

Hi I am trying to write PHPUnit tests to test my login controller and my code seems to be running fine in the browser but when I run the php unit test I get the following error

**Error:**

```
Call to a member function with() on a non-object
```

**Method:**

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::only('email', 'password');
    $attempt = Auth::attempt($input);

    if($attempt){
        return Redirect::intended('/')
            ->with('flash_message', Lang::get('sessions.you_have_logged_in'));
    }
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
public function testStore()
{
    Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(true);

    Redirect::shouldReceive('intended')
            ->once();

    $this->call('POST', 'session');
}
```

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to using mockery so I guess the problem may lay with how I am mocking the Redirect Object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from Redirect::shouldReceive(...)

```
public function testStore()
{
    Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);

    Redirect::shouldReceive('intended')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($redirectResponse = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse'));

    $this->call('POST', 'session');
}
```

The Redirect is receiving "intended" properly but, per the actual function it returns something (specifically an instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)

You can look at Illuminate\Routing\Redirector for further insight.